# IQ generation separation

Tags: digital-communications, demodulation

To generate I & Q samples from data samples `S`

```
I = S(1:2:length(S)-1) * cos(2*pi*f*t) ;
Q = S(2:2:length(S)  ) * sin(2*pi*f*t) ;
```

I & Q to integer arithmetic

```
I = I * (2^16) ;
Q = Q * (2^16) ;
```

I Q combined

```
y = bitshiftleft(Q, 16) ; 
y = bitor(y, I);
```

and mixed with carrier `fc`

```
y = y * cos(2*pi*fc*t) ;
```

To recover the I & Q, we do:

after mixing `y` with the carrier `fc` to get baseband `y`, we do

```
Q = bitand(y, 0xFFFF0000) ;
Q = bitshiftright(Q, 16) ;
I = bitand(y, 0x0000FFFF) ;
```

I am assuming dividing is the reverse of the above multiplication

```
I = I / cos(2*pi*f*t) ;  
Q = Q / sin(2*pi*f*t) ;
```

My question is the above  correct especially dividing by `cos` and `sin`?
I am not sure how to calculate `t` in all the above.

Please help.

Comment: Hi Adam! What's the origin of this processing chain ? Where did you get the idea from ?

Comment: a special data communication system, not following any standard.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is putting the I and Q samples on a "sub-carrier" at frequency $f$. If that is really what you wanted to do, the typical demodulation approach is to multiply by the sub-carrier again and low pass filter to get I or Q. Dividing by cosine or sine creates time samples that go to infinity since you will divide by zero with those functions. The multiplication operation produces a baseband component and a component at twice the carrier frequency; this is made clearer with a quick refresh of the following trigonometric identities:

\begin{align}
\cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta) &= \frac{1}{2}\cos(\alpha-\beta)+\frac{1}{2}\cos(\alpha+\beta)\\
\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta) &= \frac{1}{2}\cos(\alpha-\beta)-\frac{1}{2}\cos(\alpha+\beta)\\
\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta) &= \frac{1}{2}\sin(\alpha-\beta)+\frac{1}{2}\sin(\alpha+\beta)
\end{align}

So in your case:

$$
\cos(2\pi ft)\cos(2\pi ft) = \frac{1}{2}\cos(0)+\frac{1}{2}\cos(2\pi ft) = \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{2}\cos(4\pi ft)
$$

The $\frac{1}{2}$ represents the amplitude of I and the $\frac{1}{2}\cos(4\pi ft)$ is the doubled frequency component that is removed with a low pass filter.

However I am not sure that you intended or need to have such a "sub-carrier"? If you were going to simulate QPSK modulation for example, you can modulate directly to your final carrier as in:

\begin{align}
I_t &= I \cos(2\pi f_c t), \quad\text{where}\quad I = {1,-1}\\
Q_t &= Q \sin(2\pi f_c t), \quad\text{where}\quad Q = {1,-1}
\end{align}

And further the I and Q samples are sent simultaneously by adding the modulated outputs $I_t$ and $Q_t$ above (hence the increased data rate; we send two bits in each "symbol).

To demodulate, assuming we have done the carrier recovery work to have a good estimate of $f_c$ with all phase offsets removed, we can multiply the received sequence by $2\cos(2\pi f_c t)$ and low pass filter to recover I, and multiply the received sequence by $2\sin(2\pi f_c t)$ and low pass filter to recover Q:

Noting the demodulation steps below where LPF() denotes removing the $2f_c$ frequency component with a low pass filter:

\begin{align}
I &= LPF\big\{2 I_t\cos(2\pi f_c t)\big\}\\ 
Q &= LPF\big\{2 Q_t\sin(2\pi f_c t)\big\}
\end{align}

The Q component goes to zero on the I output since the result is in the $\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta)$ form resulting in $\sin(0) = 0$:

$$ 
0 = LPF\big\{2 Q_t\cos(2\pi f_c t)\big\}
$$

And similarly the I component goes to zero on the Q output:

$$
0 = LPF\big\{2 I_t\sin(2\pi f_c t)\big\}
$$

Therefore we can "multiplex" I and Q together given this ability to separate the two that operate simultaneously and independently in time.

Note I highly prefer to think and model using exponential frequency terms instead of sines and cosines - it is so much simpler! In fact this best explains implementations with I and Q paths as well, since to implement a complex signal you will need two real sequences $(e^{j\omega t} = \cos(\omega t) + j\sin(\omega t))$. Please see [Frequency shifting of a quadrature mixed signal](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31355/frequency-shifting-of-a-quadrature-mixed-signal/31360#31360) for more details on that.