Visualizing complex baseband signal
I am trying to visualize complex baseband representation of two signals, something like the below image,

The spectrum is not symmetric and contains two different frequency information, i am trying to do this in gnuradio with a sine and a sinc, this is the flow graph,

the spectrum i got is,

i was expecting something like a peak alone in positive spectrum for sine and a rectangle on the negative side.
I am trying to understand how the complex baseband signals containing two different information is constructed and want to see the two different frequency content at baseband. How can i do it?

This may help:
A single positive tone would be represented as the complex signal $x[n]$ as follows:
$$x_1[n] = e^{j\omega_1 n}$$
This specifically, if processed with the complex input FFT spectrum, would appear as a single positive frequency tone. We can see how to generate such a signal with two real signals $I[n]$ and $Q[n]$ to create the one complex signal $I[n]+jQ[n]$ as follows:
$$x_1[n] = \cos(\omega_1 n)+ j\sin(\omega_1 n)$$
Thus if you create a cosine and apply to the real input of the float to complex block, and then create a sine of the same frequency and apply that to the imaginary input of the float to complex block, the output of that would represent a single positive frequency.
If you want to add another signal along the negative frequency axis, this can be created with the same process using $x_2[n] = e^{-j\omega_2 n} =  \cos(\omega_2 n)- j\sin(\omega_2 n)$, and then add the two signals before processing with the complex FFT block.
These are derived from the analytic signal representations of a sinusoid. The analytic signal has the property that it will only occupy the positive frequencies and is defined as:
$$x_a[n] = x[n] + j\hat{x}[n]$$
Where:
$x[n]$ is a real signal (typically, but need not be).
$\hat{x}[n]$ is the Hilbert Transform of $x[n]$
$x_a[n]$ is the analytic signal representation of $x[n]$
The 'hilbert' command in Matlab, Octave and Python's scipy.signal actually returns the complex analytic signal; the imaginary part of which is the actual Hilbert Transform.
That said, if you want to see a peak of the sine alone on the positive axis, create the $e^{j\omega_1 n}$ signal as directed above. To see a rectangular pulse in the negative frequency axis, you can frequency translate the sinc by multiplying it with the negative frequency tone $x_2[n]$ as $y[n] = sinc(\omega_c n/\pi) e^{-j\omega_2 n} = sinc(\omega_c n/\pi)\cos(\omega_2 n) - j sinc(\omega_c n/\pi)\sin(\omega_2 n)$ which will work (according to Bedrosian's Theorem) as long as the frequency $\omega_2 $ is higher than the cut-off frequency $\omega_c$ of the Sinc.

Is this how it works irl?, when i was studying about gps signals, i didn't see the use of hilbert transform there.  The gps signal, $$ s(t) = \left( C/A \oplus D(t) \right)sin(2 \pi f_{L1} t) + \left( P(Y) \oplus D(t) \right) cos(2 \pi f_{L1} t) $$. Is this because of the quadrature modulation?

quadrature modulation with putting one signal on I and another on Q is not putting one signal in the positive frequency axis and the other in the negative. With GPS the I signal is complex conjugate symmetric (so positive and negative frequencies) and the Q signal as an independent signal is also complex conjugate symmetric. This isn't what you set out to do here.

Let's say I create a signal which looks like the very first image in my question and i modulate to $f_c$. Since the transmitted signal is real, i get a mirrored spectrum around DC. For $[f_c , f_c+W]$, i get a square spectrum and for  $[f_c-W, fc]$ i get a square with top left corner cut-off. But for gps signal from $[f_c-W, f_c+W]$ the signal is mirrored at $f_c$, right?. Can you give an example of where the former is used (first image) and is it used for communication? it looks like i can transmit more the QPSK, QAM etc.

No GPS when considering both C/A and P as a combined signal is not symmetric as you describe. The C/A code as a completely real signal at baseband on its own would be. and the P code as a completely imaginary signal at baseband also would be. But when you sum the two and consider the spectrum of the combined signal (as we do with QPSK as well) the spectrum is not symmetric about fc.

This answer may also help you: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31355/frequency-shifting-of-a-quadrature-mixed-signal/31360#31360

So, its the same as the first image?. Also, in the last para of your answer, you mentioned about frequency translation of sinc by $e^{-jw_2n}$, wouldn't this move both the positive and negative frequencies to the negative freq axis?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
