# Zone Plate Reconstruction

Tags: image-processing, filters, sampling, filtering

I am trying to reconstruct the Zone Plate image and am struggling to remove the last remaining aliasing. 
[image]
ShaderToy: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/wdGGWK

In the shader above you can see that I am sampling each pixel independently 1000 times with [-3, 3] jitter, and filtering those samples with (currently) Lanczos2. Why is there still aliasing?

My understanding is that the aliasing just at the edge of the visible pattern is from the filter and can't be removed without a different choice of filter, but the subtle aliasing in the middle of the axis seems like an error, and one that I have been unable to remove.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Lanczos2 has a frequency response peak of about -40 dB or 0.01 at about 0.9 times the sampling frequency, see [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/44709/15347). Your peak aliasing outside the main lobe is just left from where the aliasing goes to zero frequency so I think it is the same peak. The amplitude of the aliasing is also roughly as expected.

So I don't see any error by you.

Comment: I updated the image with labels on the different aliasing lobes. So it's your understanding that the filter is responsible for all 4? I would have guessed that the filter induced the A lobe, but the remaining 3 are due to something else. I'm happy with the amplitude of the C and D lobes - is there a better filter that can make the B lobe more like C and D?

Comment: I believe the filter is responsible for A and B (and probably C and D). A originates from a frequency about half the sampling frequency. You could use a better filter. My suggested improvement to Lanczos2 in the linked question should reduce B a bit.

Comment: See [here](http://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2011/g_lmii/revisions/2011-09-27/g_lmii/680x302-kernels-lanczos.png) for Lanczos2 and Lanczos3 frequency response comparison.