# Generating Kawase Blur Kernels to Approximate a Gaussian Blur on an Image

Tags: filters, image-processing, blur, gaussian-kernel

Is there an algorithm to generate the Kawase Blur Kernels to approximate the actual Gaussian Blur (of a specific kernel size, and if possible, a sigma)?

Comment: Sounds interesting! Do you have a link to a description of what a *kawase blur kernel* is?

Comment: To the extent this is helpful- you can generate the equivalent of a FIR filter with Gaussian coefficients simply by cascading a series of two tap unity gain FIR filters-- similar to convolving binomial distributions (and the law of large averages), it converges quickly, such as 6+ stages, to a reasonable Gaussian response.  See https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31483/gaussian-fir-filter-with-no-multipliers

Comment: @MarcusMüller I might not be using the correct terminology. I am talking about the distances of the four corners we average in each pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [Intel - An Investigation of Fast Real Time GPU Based Image Blur Algorithms By Filip Strugar](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/07/15/an-investigation-of-fast-real-time-gpu-based-image-blur-algorithms) it looks like the Kawase kernel is just a way of implementing a linear kernel quickly, but in a way that constrains the kernel somewhat.

This means that **you** could make such an algorithm.  Either choose a set of spreads and adjust their weights (if that is possible) for a best fit, or search a number of possible spreads (with the best weights) and find the ones that fit best.

Given the ad-hoc nature of the kernel I suspect you'll end up with a table of best fits for each set of spreads, and then you (or anyone using the table) would want to make a judgement call about effect vs. clock ticks.

The kernel is designed with some specific hardware in mind, so you'll need to check to see if you *can* adjust the weights at all, or if you can only adjust the spacing and the repetition at each spacing.  At any rate, because the spacing is discrete, its a fairly highly nonlinear optimization problem.  It may be best to just do a brute-force search at each size of Gaussian you want to emulate.  Just try out a bunch of different spacing combinations, and see which ones give you the closest match to a Gaussian of a certain size for the number of iterations.

Comment: Could you elaborate how I would find the best distances & then further adjust their weights?

Comment: Everything I know about that kernel comes from reading that one page I cite.  So -- not much.  But see my edits.